# Makefile recursive install?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have the following: A chain of dependencies, each of which may or may not be present, and each of which installs in the exact same way (with the exception being the string name of the dependency). In order to get rid of repetitive makefile code, I prototype the following function:

```
define install_utility = 
$(1):
# recursion
$(foreach bar, $(1)_dependencies,$(eval $(call install_utility,$(bar)))
ifeq(`which $(1)`,)        # check for existence of dependency
    echo will install $(1) # show me make is executing expected commands
endif
endef

foo_dependencies=A B
foo=foo
eval $(call install_utility,$(foo))


# Expected results: 
will install A
will install B
will install foo

# Actual result: no error message, just: 
... (infinite loop that prints nothing)
```

And when I run, I get the following error: an infinite loop.

This seems like really simple functionality.  However, I am having trouble getting it to work in make. Is there a manner in which I am "expected" to do this in make?

---

Have tinkered a bit... and getting a variety of errors depending on whether I tab out the recursion:

```
$(1):
    $(foreach bar, ...

ifeq(`which $(1)`,)
    ...

# error messages:
make: *** no rule to make target '$(foo_dependencies)
ifeq(`which', needed by 'foo'. Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do... it looks extremely non-make-like to me.

But, this definitely will not work:

```
ifeq(`which $(1)`,)
```

If you want this to be part of the recipe, you have to indent it with a TAB character and write it in shell syntax, not make syntax.

If you want this to be part of the makefile (not the recipe) you need to write it in correct make syntax: first you have to include a space between the `ifeq` and the `(`.  Second, make does not support backquotes.  If you want to run a shell command you have to use the `$(shell ...)` function.

Comment: sounds like I need to find a different way--and discovered remake, so maybe I will be able to tool around with that.  Thanks for stopping the time hemorrhage, at least

Comment: Why are you trying to write expanded recipes using `eval`?  Why not just write prerequisites directly?  It looks like you're trying to reinvent what make does naturally by forcing it to use recursion and expansion.